# Set Theory Expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\{n | n \in \mathbb N \text{ and } n\cdot n + n \text{ is a multiple of } 5 \text { and } n \leq 12\}$$

I put $\{4,5,9,10\}$ but apparently this is still a proper set not the complete answer?

Comment: Is, according to your definitions, $0 \in N$?

Comment: Depends on whether your math teacher considers $0$ a natural number, but most set theory books do.

Comment: Also what was the edit?

Comment: I edited for formatting (you had $<=$ for example.  Just tweaks to the format.  You can click on the "Edited..." text to get a diff of the edit.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to be profane in the comments, even if the teacher is not behaving ideally...

Comment: @JamieB: Because then she would deprive you of the exercise of *figuring out for yourself* that you were missing 0. Remember, the point of an exercise is usually not to get the solution, but to learn *how to solve problems*. You don't get any problem solving experience if you're simply *told* what you did wrong, rather than working it out for yourself.

Comment: I guess it's one of these 'You'd have to see to understand'. Also for the others, I don't consider my comment profane, maybe culture clash there, swearing would be much worse than that :)

Comment: Math teachers may consider 0 a natural number, but number theorists know that it isn't.

Comment: I actually prefer the notation that I've heard Peano himself used: $\mathbb N$ for the natural numbers *without* $0$, and $\mathbb N_0$ for the natural numbers *with* $0$.

Comment: @Gerry: And set theorists know that number theorists are just wrong... :-)

Comment: @Asaf, Rule #1: Number theorists are always right. Rule #2: If a number theorist is wrong, see Rule #1.

Comment: @Gerry: Rule #1 implies a contradiction; therefore Rule #2 is consistent relative to it.

Answer (score 1):

To make the search easier, I would think of $n*n +n$ as $n * ( n + 1)$, so then you just have to multiply consecutive digits together as see if there is a $5$ as the last digit. This gives the four values you give, along with 0.

Comment: $5$ is odd. Therefore it is odd if you get $5$ as the last digit when you multiply two consecutive digits.

Comment: long with thinking of this as $n(n+1)$ remember that if $k\mid ab$ then either $k \mid a$ or $k \mid b$ so in order to $5 \mid n(n+1)$  either $5\mid n$ or $5 \mid (n+1)$